# Lawnchair code executing twice

Tags: javascript, lawnchair

I am trying to use Lawnchair and have found that it seems to execute all functions twice.  This may be just something I am doing wrong with JavaScript in general.  Here is and example that does nothing other than demonstrate my problem.

```
console.log("Flag 1");

Lawnchair(function() {
    console.log("Flag 2");
});
```

In this example the console shows this.

```
Flag 1
Flag 2
Flag 2
```

So while the whole section of code is only getting called once, the inner function is indeed getting called twice.

Is this a syntax problem?

Comment: I have no idea, but on my own, I would put a console.log("Flag 3"); under then function declaration, and sprinkle some alert("alert N"); messages to see what's happening when.

Comment: I ran the same code in Firefox and saw "Flag 2" only once, so I think it's something else in your code.  Can you post more code in your question?

Comment: I think this is possibly a bug in Lawnchair. my call backs are called twice as well, there is supposed to be a work around where you instantiate properly, but it didn't work for me.